# Scraping with pandas, beautifulsoup, urllib: How to retrieve possibly embedded fields

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, urllib

I know there are questions like this, I was trying to follow them. I am trying to scrape the info in [this](http://isyslab.info/StraPep/show_detail.php?id=BP1000) page. Ideally I would like as much of the info as possible into a clean/easy to read tsv, but the essential parts to scrape are: ID, Name, Organism, Family, Classification, UniProt ID, Modifications, Sequence and PDB structure IDs (e.g. in this case, there is a list of PDB structures, the first is 1BAS and the last is 4OEG).

I wrote this in python3:

```
import urllib.request
import sys
import pandas as pd
import bs4

out = open('pdb.parsed.txt', 'a')
for i in range(1000,1005):
#        try:
            url = 'http://isyslab.info/StraPep/show_detail.php?id=BP' + str(i)
            page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
            soup = pd.read_html(page)
            print(soup)
```

I have attached my output here:
[image]

I have two questions:

1. You can see that some of the info that I require is missing (e.g. the sequence has NaN).
2. More importantly, I cannot see any field that correlates to the list of PDB IDs?

I was hoping to use pd.read_html if possible because in the past I have struggled with urllib/bs4, and I have found that I have been more successful with pd.read_html in recent scraping attempts. Can anyone explain how I could pull out the fields that I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you were unable to scrape entries from certain rows such as the 'Sequence' row because these rows were populated by Javascript. The approach that worked for me was to use a combination of Selenium with a Firefox driver to grab the page's html code, and then use Beautiful Soup to parse that code.

Here's how I was able to scrape the pertinent info for the ID, Name, Organism, Family, Classification, UniProt ID, Modifications, Sequence and PDB structure IDs, for each page:

```
import urllib.request
import sys
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import csv

pages = []
for page in range(1000,1005):
#        try:
    info_dict = {}
    url = 'http://isyslab.info/StraPep/show_detail.php?id=BP' + str(page)
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(url)
    html = driver.page_source
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    main_table = bs.find('table', attrs={'class': 'main_table'})
    rows = main_table.findAll('tr')
    for row in rows:
        try: # We only want rows from a page where both row title and text are not null
            row_header = row.find('th').text
            row_text = row.find('td').text
        except:
            pass
        else:
            if row_header and row_text:
                if row_header in ['ID', 'Name', 'Organism', 'Family', 'Classification', 'UniProt ID']:
                    info_dict[row_header] = row_text
                elif row_header == 'Modification':
                    try: # Some pages have a null table entry for 'Modification'
                        mod_text = row.find('table').find('td').text
                    except:
                        pass
                    else:
                        if mod_text:
                            info_dict[row_header] = mod_text
                        else:
                            info_dict[row_header] = 'NA'
                # Pass 'Sequence' and 'Structure' as space separated strings
                elif row_header == 'Sequence':
                    seqs = ''
                    for i in row_text.split():
                        seqs += ' ' + i
                    info_dict[row_header] = seqs[1:]
                elif row_header == 'Structure':
                    pdb_ids = ''
                    a = row.find('tbody').find_all('a')
                    for i in a:
                        if i.text != '[x]': pdb_ids += ' ' + i.text
                    info_dict[row_header] = pdb_ids[1:]
    pages.append(info_dict)

keys = pages[0].keys()
with open('pdb.parsed.txt', 'a') as output_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(pages) # Add a tab-delimited row for each page we scraped
```

I can then read in the .tsv file I just created as a dataframe if I want:

```
df = pd.read_csv('pdb.parsed.txt', delimiter='\t')
```

It looks like this:
[image: df]

Although the contents of columns containing longer strings (such as 'Sequence') are abbreviated, we can verify that the entire sequence is indeed present:

```
df.iloc[0]['Sequence']

'PALPEDGGSG AFPPGHFKDP KRLYCKNGGF FLRIHPDGRV DGVREKSDPH IKLQLQAEER GVVSIKGVCA NRYLAMKEDG RLLASKCVTD ECFFFERLES NNYNTYRSRK YTSWYVALKR TGQYKLGSKT GPGQKAILFL PMSAKS'
```

The contents of the saved tsv file look like this:

```
ID  Name    Organism    Family  Classification  UniProt ID  Modification    Sequence    Structure
BP1000  Fibroblast growth factor 2  Homo sapiens    heparin-binding growth factors family   Cytokine/Growth factor  FGF2_HUMAN  Phosphotyrosine; by TEC PALPEDGGSG AFPPGHFKDP KRLYCKNGGF FLRIHPDGRV DGVREKSDPH IKLQLQAEER GVVSIKGVCA NRYLAMKEDG RLLASKCVTD ECFFFERLES NNYNTYRSRK YTSWYVALKR TGQYKLGSKT GPGQKAILFL PMSAKS    1BAS 1BFB 1BFC 1BFF 1BFG 1BLA 1BLD 1CVS 1EV2 1FGA 1FQ9 1II4 1IIL 2BFH 2FGF 2M49 4FGF 4OEE 4OEF 4OEG
BP1001  Interleukin-2   Homo sapiens    IL-2 family Cytokine/Growth factor  IL2_HUMAN       APTSSSTKKT QLQLEHLLLD LQMILNGINN YKNPKLTRML TFKFYMPKKA TELKHLQCLE EELKPLEEVL NLAQSKNFHL RPRDLISNIN VIVLELKGSE TTFMCEYADE TATIVEFLNR WITFCQSIIS TLT  1IRL 1M47 1M48 1M49 1M4A 1M4B 1M4C 1NBP 1PW6 1PY2 1QVN 1Z92 2B5I 2ERJ 3INK 3QAZ 3QB1 4NEJ 4NEM
BP1002  Insulin Bos taurus  insulin family  Hormone INS_BOVIN       GIVEQCCASV CSLYQLENYC N 1APH 1BPH 1CPH 1DPH 1PID 2A3G 2BN1 2BN3 2INS 2ZP6 3W14 4BS3 4E7T 4E7U 4E7V 4I5Y 4I5Z 4IDW 4IHN 4M4F 4M4H 4M4I 4M4J 4M4L 4M4M
BP1003  Interleukin-1 beta  Homo sapiens    IL-1 family Cytokine/Growth factor  IL1B_HUMAN      APVRSLNCTL RDSQQKSLVM SGPYELKALH LQGQDMEQQV VFSMSFVQGE ESNDKIPVAL GLKEKNLYLS CVLKDDKPTL QLESVDPKNY PKKKMEKRFV FNKIEINNKL EFESAQFPNW YISTSQAENM PVFLGGTKGG QDITDFTMQF VSS    1HIB 1I1B 1IOB 1ITB 1L2H 1S0L 1T4Q 1TOO 1TP0 1TWE 1TWM 21BI 2I1B 2KH2 2NVH 31BI 3LTQ 3O4O 3POK 41BI 4DEP 4G6J 4G6M 4GAF 4GAI 4I1B 5BVP 5I1B 6I1B 7I1B 9ILB
BP1004  Lactoferricin-H Homo sapiens    transferrin family  Antimicrobial   TRFL_HUMAN      GRRRSVQWCA VSQPEATKCF QWQRNMRKVR GPPVSCIKRD SPIQCIQA    1Z6V 1XV4 1XV7 1Z6W 2GMC 2GMD
```

I used the following to Anaconda commands to install Selenium, and then the Firefox driver:

```
conda install -c conda-forge selenium
conda install -c conda-forge geckodriver
```